# How exactly works the JavaScript object? Can i declare a function as a field of a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, html, json, javascript-objects

I am pretty new in JavaScript and I always used it in something like old procedural way.

Now I am studying how to JavaScript implement the object oriented paradigm and I have some doubt on this example found on a tutorial.

I have an **utility.js** file that contain this simple code:

```
var steveApp = {};  // Object container

steveApp.person = 'Steve';  // Add a person field to the steveApp object

steveApp.logPerson = function() {
    console.log(steveApp.person);
}
```

So I have some doubt about how it works exactly.

I think that first it define something like an **empty object** named **steveApp** by this line:

```
var steveApp = {};  // Object container
```

Then I think that the **.** it is used to add a field to the previous empty object, so I have:

```
steveApp.person = 'Steve';
```

that add a valorized person field to the steveApp object.

Finally it do a "strange" thing:

```
steveApp.logPerson = function() {
    console.log(steveApp.person);
}
```

It seems to me that add a new field (named **logPerson**) to the **steveApp** object but this field is not a normal field (an integer, a string or another object) but it is a function that perform a behvavior (write a log in the console).

Then, into another JavaScript, file it do:

```
steveApp.logPerson();
```

and the previous function is performed. So what exactly does it mean? It means that in JavaScript a function could be a field of an object or what?

And why to call this function (if it is true that it is a field) I have to do:

```
steveApp.logPerson();
```

and not call the field name ?:

```
steveApp.logPerson;
```

Comment: Almost all of your assumptions are correct. The `()` are required because *all* function calls require them. `console.log` is just a reference to the function (itself a member of `console`); `console.log()` actually *calls* the function.

Comment: A variable in javascript can hold a function as value, yes. But you should read a little from good sources instead of just guessing. Here's the MDN about OOP: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: Functions are values in JavaScript, just like other objects.

Comment: Please note that while `{}` has no own properties so could be called _empty_, it still has an inheritance chain to `Object.prototype` which will give it things like _toString_. To create a truely empty _Object_ you need to do `Object.create(null);`

Answer (score 2):

Functions are first class objects in JavaScript. They can be treated just like any other kind of data.

You can store them in variables, store them in properties, pass them as function arguments, etc.

---

> Abd why to call this function (if it is true that it is a field) I have to do:
>
> steveApp.logPerson();

Putting `(zero_or_more_aguments_here)` after something that evaluates as a function is how you *call* a function. Leaving them off gives you the function itself, not the result of calling it.

Comment: When Quentin calls _functions Objects_ here, that is really literal. _Functions_ can be given properties (they already have some native ones) and they also inherit from `Function.prototype` which inherits from `Object.prototype`. `(function () {} instanceof Object); // true`

Answer (score 1):

```
steveApp.logPerson(); //calls the function
```

while

```
steveApp.logPerson; // returns the function itself (NOT the return value of the function
```

you can also print it in the console and you will see:

```
console.log(steveApp.logPerson())
```

vs

```
console.log(steveApp.logPerson);
```

greetings

Answer (score 0):

The basics is that JavaScript is not strongly typed, so you could even assign different types to the same variables at different times:

```
var myVar = true;
myVar = 3.14;
myVar = "now a string";
alert("myVar is now a string with content: " + myVar);
myVar = function (someArg) {
    alert("myVar is now a reference to a function, passed argument " + someArg);
    return true;
}
myVar();

typeof myVar; // would return "function"
typeof myVar(); // would return "boolean"
```

As for your object "fields" (usually called properties), indeed they can receive any type that a normal variable would as well. Including a function, since they are "first-class citizen".

```
var myObject = {
    myBool: true,
    myNumber: 3.14,
    myMethod: function (myArg) {
        return myArg;
    },
    myNull: null
};
```

And like previously, you can even re-assign them later on…

Answer (score 0):

Your assumptions are correct. But the difference between the below lines are

```
steveApp.logPerson();
```

Accessing logPerson property and *invokes* it as a function using `()`

```
steveApp.logPerson;
```

It is just accessing the property logPerson,  it returns the reference/value if it is used in RHS in an equation.

---

If you consider programming language like Scala, it is intelligent enough to infer whether it is a function call or not without using `()` but in JavaScript it is the reference, and if you try to invoke a normal property which is not a function. You will get an error saying `logPerson is not a function`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Quentin & I quote:

> Functions are first class objects in JavaScript. They can be treated
>   just like any other kind of data.
>
> You can store them in variables, store them in properties, pass them
>   as function arguments, etc.

Another important thing to know is that objects in JS are  passed around or called by reference. **They are never copied.**

```
var a = {};
var b = {};
a.test = "hello";
b.test   // returns undefined
```

Also

```
var a = {};
var b = a;
a.test = "hello"
b.test // return "hello"
```

And

```
var stooge = {first: "Jerome", second: "Howard"}
var x = stooge;
x.nickname = "curly";
var nick = stooge.nickname;
nick // returns "Curly"
```